# Java Sockets - Client message not reaching Server

Tags: java, loops, sockets, server, client

currently I am trying to send multiple messages from a client to a server and echo them on the server but somehow my message is not arriving at the server until i press CTRL+Z(D) and hit enter.
My loop runs as long as the user does not enter "quit" but altough I write my message to the OutputStream and flush it my message does not show on the Server side as if my Client still reads input.

(I do not want to use BufferedReaders or Threads at the moment it's purely for learning reasons.)

Would be nice if someone could tell me where my mistake/error lies.
Read also the javadocs but still can not find my mistake.

Client.java

```
public class Client {
//class members
private String msg = null;
private Scanner scn = null;

public Client(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
    //Connect to Server
    try(Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port))
    {
        //Initialize class members
        scn = new Scanner(System.in); //Init Scanner
        msg="";

        System.out.println("Enter message:");
        //Write to Socket
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();    
        while(!msg.equals("quit"))
        {
            msg=scn.nextLine();
            out.write(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.length());
            out.flush();
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server {
//class members
private String msg = null;

public Server(int port) throws IOException {
    //Setup ServerSocket.
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("SERVER: Launched service.");
    //Accept incoming connection requests.
    while(true) {
        try(Socket connection = server.accept())
        {
            System.out.println("SERVER: Client connection accepted.");

            //Read Input
            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            for(int c=in.read(); c!=-1; c=in.read())
            {
                line.append((char) c);
            }
            System.out.println(line);

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("SERVER: Client disconnected!");
        }
    }
}
```

sincerely,
rhyleigh

Answer (score 0):

- Your server prints nothing until `read()` returns -1.
- `read()` returns -1 at end of stream.
- Over a TCP socket, end of stream is only caused by the peer closing the connection.
- Your server's peer, i.e. the client, doesn't close the connection until you type ^Z at the terminal. which causes an unstated exception to be thrown.

Your program is working as designed.